# Why can the row count increase during a Snowflake query?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, projection

See query profile (flowchart).

Row count increased from 20,211 to 20,227 during the Projection step of the query.

Any idea as to why?

Edit: If relevant, here's the obfuscated query:

```
SELECT   
    x1, ..., xn   
FROM   
    someschema.sometable   
    SAMPLE (10000 rows)  
WHERE    
    somedate > ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE::date, -12) --past 12 months only   
    and x1 > 0 and ... and xn > 0  
    and sometime > 30   
    and (somesetting = 'a' or somesetting = 'b')
```

[image]

Comment: Care to share your query?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa just added.